# Node.js user authentication and unprotected routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication

I couldn't come up with a better name for the question so I apologize for that.

In my application you can make an account, create files and send the link of a file you created in a "view-version" to whoever you want.

The routes to create, delete, read,... files are protected, however, the "view-version" is not.

The way I handle it right now is the following:

The link to the view-version consists of the id of the file and a token the user receives upon log in.
When whoever receives the link opens the page, the token and id (that's the id of the entry created in MongoDB) are authenticated and if they are valid the user sees the page.
Obviously, the token times out after some time and I'm assuming that, once the token times out, the viewer will no longer be able to view the page (I didn't actually test this but it just makes sense I guess).

I'm new to creating websites that require user authentication for certain sites so I'm rather clueless about how to solve this.

If I let the viewer access the file just using the id, that'd be insecure since he could view ALL files by trying different id's (a viewer is not supposed to be able to view all files).
So, I guess what I'm trying to do is to publish the view-version of a certain file to a selected audience.

I was thinking about creating a permanent token that I could use instead of the token created when logging in/out so the viewer would always be able to view the files but I'm not sure how big of a security risk that is.

I tried googling how to best go about that, however, my search was unsuccessful.
How is such a concept usually implemented?

Comment: Looks like you could consider the common cookie authentication approach, where the token is put into a cookie. However, the description of the issue is vague, in particular, there's no clear explanation on how user sessions are related to published links. I am not sure then if this direction solves your issue.

Comment: The way I'm doing it right now is that, if a user logs, a jwt is created on the backend and sent to the client where it's stored in a cookie. The token is sent with every request the user makes.The link to the public version of a document contains this token and since the token expires after a certain amount of time, I'm assuming the token in the link will not work/ authenticate anymore

Comment: So you are sending the login token of users to their friends?

Comment: yeah basically but since that's not secure at all I need another solution

Comment: what I did for now was to create a second token upon login which you use to log in that is not used to send back to the server whenever you make requests. That still means if the viewer tries a few random file id's and gets lucky he could easily access all other files. I somehow need to create a token for each file but I'm not sure how to do that